# Truncate a set of lists until a subset of entries matches?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Consider lists of vectors of elements like

```
list[1]={{a1,b1,c11},{a2,b2,c12},{a3,b3,c13},{a4,b4,c14},{a5,b5,c15}};
list[2]={{a1,b1,c21}            ,{a3,b3,c23},{a4,b4,c24},{a5,b5,c25}};
list[3]={{a1,b1,c31},{a2,b2,c32},{a3,b3,c33}            ,{a5,b5,c35}};
```

where the length 3 of vectors in lists is just an example and could be longer, and there may be more than 3 such lists.

I would like to have a function `truncate[listoflists_]` that takes all these lists and truncates them to only have the vectors containing `ai,bi` entries that are present in all of them:

```
{list[1],list[2],list[3]}=truncate[{list[1],list[2],list[3]}];
list[1]
list[2]
list[3]
```

> {{a1,b1,c11},{a3,b3,c13},{a5,b5,c15}}
>
> {{a1,b1,c21},{a3,b3,c23},{a5,b5,c25}}
>
> {{a1,b1,c31},{a3,b3,c33},{a5,b5,c35}}

Is there a quick way to do this in Mathematica? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is short (does not mean quick) to get it via associations:

```
truncate = Values @ KeyIntersection @ Map[#[[;; 2]] -> # &, #, {2}] &
```

We convert `{a1,b1,c11}` to `{a1,b1}->{a1,b1,c11}` and everything else is straightforward.

Comment: Love it when a mod ends up in the LQ review. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 ok, explanation added.

Comment: I approved it anyway.   It's not always clear that excessive exposition would be an improvement.

Comment: I have changed it to `truncate = 
 Values@KeyIntersection@Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> # &, #, {2}] &` to make it compatible with longer vector cases.

Comment: @Kagaratsch right, you mentioned it. I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
tF = Module[{i = Intersection@@#[[;;, ;;, #2]], k = #2}, Select[MemberQ[i, #[[k]]]&]/@ #]&

lists = list /@ {1, 2, 3};
tF[lists, {1, 2}]
```

> {{{a1, b1, c11}, {a3, b3, c13}, {a5, b5, c15}},
>    {{a1, b1, c21}, {a3,  b3, c23}, {a5, b5, c25}},
>   {{a1, b1, c31}, {a3, b3, c33}, {a5, b5, c35}}}